# Crop SKTexture with SKLabel text

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, sprite-kit, skspritenode

To create a button in SpriteKit, I created a rounded rectangle with a SKShapeNode and then placed a SKLabel on top of it.

It looks like this:
[image]

I want to have the background that is under the label change with whatever is under it. So inside the picture the T, E and half the A would be purple.

Is there some way to halfway color the font? Or somehow crop the white rectangle texture with the SKLabel that is placed on it. This way there is no label but instead a cut out of a label from the texture. Basically, I want the font color to be whatever is behind it.

I have to do this without importing images and through code somehow.

Comment: You can do Subtractive blending.  Make your label white, make your box white, set your `blendMode` to `.subtract`, then extract the texture using `view.textureFromNode` to use on an SKSpriteNode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Knight0fDragon have reason in his comment, this is a good suggestion. There is another solution you can do without `textureFromNode`.
You can prepare your `cropNode` with the background and the label, then make another background clone with the button and your cropNode over all:

```
import SpriteKit
class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        let background = SKSpriteNode.init(imageNamed: "background.png")
        background.zPosition = 1
        let background2 = background.copy() as! SKSpriteNode
        //label
        let titleLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "AvenirNext-Bold")
        titleLabel.fontSize = 150
        titleLabel.fontColor = SKColor.black
        titleLabel.text = "RATE"
        titleLabel.horizontalAlignmentMode = .center
        titleLabel.zPosition = 5
        titleLabel.blendMode = .subtract
        //cropNode
        let cropNode = SKCropNode()
        cropNode.addChild(background)
        cropNode.maskNode = titleLabel
        self.addChild(cropNode)
        cropNode.zPosition = 5
        //button
        let button = SKShapeNode(rect: CGRect(x: -300, y: -50, width: 600, height: 200), cornerRadius: 100)
        button.zPosition = 4
        button.fillColor = SKColor.white
        self.addChild(background2)
        self.addChild(button)
    }
}
```

**Image used**:
[image]

**Output**:

[image]

**Another background to test:**

[image]

**Output 2:**

[image]

Comment: This is a perfect solution for static backgrounds. Would I still be able to use this method if the background is very dynamic or would blendMode be the better option? For example, inside the original picture the purple circle can grow, shrink, and move randomly. I would like these translations to update the font constantly, as if the button was actually a white texture with the word "RATE" cut out of it so you can see the background past the words. I am not sure how efficient it would be if I would have to be updating the crop node constantly (unless the changes automatically take effect?)

Comment: For dynamic purposes I suggest to realize png images that contains both label and button instead of sklabelnodes with transparency effect and skshapenode: the dynamic background can change continuosly and forces you to change everytime the cropnode and that's could become really complicated to handle..

Comment: According to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skcropnode), it says "A collection of nodes can dynamically generate a complex mask that changes each time the frame is rendered." So it is possible it updates itself? Otherwise would blendMode be better? (Trying to avoid PNG images as buttons)

Comment: @Nicholas714 I never say that is not possible: I say that you should avoid to create that architecture for all your buttons simply because in the first time could be hard to handle (you must know everytime what is your dynamic background..), then you could obtain unexpected results due to bad behaviour of some types like `SKShapeNode`. That's depend by the complexity of your game (this menu should floating like a pause menu during the game)? Think about it and choose the fastest and light way to do it..

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. The background has only one circle on it (which is a SKSpriteNode) and whenever it's size is updated I will try set the crop node. If it handels bad I will have to make it in Photoshop like you said with the text cropped out in the center.